# Using Apache to forward endpoints to different ports on the same host

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am attempting to configure Apache to treat certain endpoints of an application differently.

I need /api, /appname and /admin to forward to separate Tomcat instances on the same host, obviously operating on different ports.

Apache is listening on 443 (SSL).

Looking through Apache's docs I see examples where mod_rewrite is used for similar tasks, but not for this actual use-case.

Only ports 80 and 443 (80 is redirected to 443) are open to the outside, so the others are internal only... let's call them 2001, 3001 and 4001.

EDIT: ADDENDUM: I am using apache 2.2, without plans to update to 2.4.x at this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, you'll need to make sure that `mod_proxy` is enabled. Then, assuming that you want each of `/api/`, `/appname/`, and `/admin/` to look like a subdirectory to the enduser and that they are listening on `2001`, `3001`, and `4001` respectively, I think what you are looking for is something like this:

(in the server or vhost config)

```
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)     http://localhost:2001/$1 [P,L,QSA]
ProxyPassReverse /api/     http://localhost:2001/

RewriteRule ^/appname/(.*) http://localhost:3001/$1 [P,L,QSA]
ProxyPassReverse /appname/ http://localhost:3001/

RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*)   http://localhost:4001/$1 [P,L,QSA]
ProxyPassReverse /admin/   http://localhost:4001/
```

(in the .htaccess config ...no leading slash ...and no `mod_proxy`)

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)      http://localhost:2001/otherpath/$1 [P,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^appname/(.*)  http://localhost:3001/otherpath/$1 [P,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)    http://localhost:4001/otherpath/$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

The `$1` represents what was captured the by the parens. `P` tells mod_rewrite to use mod_proxy to handle this rewrite. `L` means to make this the last rule; to stop rewriting after this is applied. `QSA` appends the query string from the inbound request onto the rewritten request.

The `ProxyPassReverse` is used to catch any redirects from the internal instance and rewrite it to match the external URI. NB: `mod_proxy` needs to be in the server config (server, vhost, directory) and is **not valid** in `.htaccess`

Some helpful refs:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html

Now, with all that said, you'll probably not want to use `mod_rewrite` to do this anyway. It really is `mod_proxy` that is doing all the work for you. If you don't have any actual rewriting, you should be using `mod_proxy` directly. Even `mod_rewrite` just hands it off to `mod_proxy` anyway.

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/avoid.html:

> `RewriteRule` provides the `[P]` flag to pass rewritten URIs through
>   `mod_proxy`.
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^/?images(.*) http://imageserver.local/images$1 [P]
> ```
>
> However, in many cases, when there is no actual pattern matching
>   needed, as in the example shown above, the `ProxyPass` directive is a
>   better choice. The example here could be rendered as:
>
> ```
> ProxyPass /images/ http://imageserver.local/images/
> ```
>
> Note that whether you use `RewriteRule` or `ProxyPass`, you'll still
>   need to use the `ProxyPassReverse` directive to catch redirects 
>   issued from the back-end server:
>
> ```
> ProxyPassReverse /images/ http://imageserver.local/images/
> ```
>
> You may need to use RewriteRule instead when there are other 
>   RewriteRules in effect in the same scope, as a RewriteRule will 
>   usually take effect before a ProxyPass, and so may preempt what 
>   you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It fits well in my environment, and your answer contained a number of very helpful anecdotes for helping sell the solution to my team!