# Configure Apache for Angular and Tomcat on the same host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat9

***I am trying to serve my application on a `Centos 7` host, where I have deployed an `Angular` app for the frontend and `Java Spring Boot` app for the backend.***
My versions are `Apache 2.4.6`, `Tomcat 9` and `Angular 7`.

Let's say my domain is `example.com`. I want the user to write the following on the browser to access the Angular app routes, i.e. the frontend:

```
example.com/**
```

Also I would like to be able to write the following on the browser to access the Java app routes, i.e. the backend:

```
example.com/api/**
```

I tried to do it using Apache's `mod_proxy`, after reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33095758/350061. However, I only managed to serve Angular through `example.com`, while my API is only served on its original endpoint, that is `example.com:8080/my-api` and not through `example.com/api`.

These are my Apache settings:

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/example.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/my-ng-app/dist/my-ng-app"

   RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)     http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L,QSA]
   ProxyPassReverse /api/     http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

**/var/www/my-ng-app/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)      http://localhost:8080/my-api/$1 [P,L,QSA]

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

I have configured `.htaccess` to be read from that folder and verified that it is actually read. Also even if I remove the last part of `.htaccess` that redirects non-existing resources to `index.html`, the api does not get served from `example.com/api`, as I wish. It only gets served from `example.com:8080/my-api`

Any ideas on how to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of googling and trial and error, my solution consists of these changes:

1. I edited Tomcat's `server.xml` connector to serve requests through `localhost`. This made possible for rewrite settings to access my Java app through `localhost:8080`, but made impossible for me to access remotely my Java app through `example.com:8080`, which is fine.
2. I configured `SELinux` to allow `Apache` (httpd) to initiate outbound connections, in my case connections to `localhost`
3. I applied some fixes on my original `VirtualHost` and `.htaccess` configuration

More specifically:

1. ```
   sudo nano /opt/tomcat/latest/conf/server.xml
   ```

   Find the connector for port 8080 and add `address` attribute as such:

   ```
   <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              address="127.0.0.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443" />
   ```
2. ```
   /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
   ```

   The -P persist the setting for future reboots
3. ***/etc/httpd/conf.d/example.conf***

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example.com
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      DocumentRoot "/var/www/my-ng-app/dist/my-ng-app"

      RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)     http://localhost:8080/my-api/$1 [P,L,QSA]
      ProxyPassReverse /api/     http://localhost:8080/my-api/
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   ***/var/www/my-ng-app/.htaccess***

   ```
   # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]

   # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
   RewriteRule ^ /index.html
   ```

After these changes just restart `Tomcat` and `Apache` and you will be able to access your API through `example.com/api`